# Unity Top Panel spread on both dual monitor. Necessary?

Tags: 12.04, unity, panel, dualhead

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with a dual monitor setup. The Workspace is spread between the monitors in Xinerama mode, not mirror.
Now, the top panel is present on both the monitors. It's simply doubled. Not a big issue but since I added some indicators to the panel, the load of my little netbook started to increase. And seems that the unity-panel-service eat a lot of resources.
So, is there a way to run the to panel in only one monitor, like it's already possible to do with the launcher? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, and I see a problem with the menus if it's done that way.

Anyway, I don't expect that showing the panel in two monitors is consuming much more resources than displaying it only in one. So it makes little sense to remove it for performance reasons.

Comment: I see your point with the windows menu. Anyway, stopping the indicator-multiload made the load of my netbook drop from 2 to 1. The easier way seems to not run that applet after all ;)